# Resizing the text size with slider dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dialog, slider, text-size

I created a page dynamically for displaying the content. I want to resize the content text size(increase,decrease). In the dynamic page I created a button. When we click on the button "`Dialog`" box is opened with `slider`. When we moving the `slider` from left to right the content size should be increase or from right to left size should be decrease. But it does not show any effect on the size.

```
var seq = $(this).data("sequence");
        if ($('[data-role=page]#' + seq).length === 0) {
            $($.mobile.pageContainer).append('<div data-role="page" id="' + seq + '" class="items"><div data-role="content" id="desc"></div><div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="my-footer"><div data-role="popup" id="textMenu" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a"><li data-icon="false"><a href="dialog.html" id="textSize" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Text size</a></li></ul></div><div class="ui-block-a ui-bar-a" data-theme="a"><div align="left" style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;"><a href="#textMenu" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="bars" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" style="margin-top:5px;"></a></div></div><a href="" data-role="button" class="addToFavoritesDiv" style="margin-top:5px;">Bookmark</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="ui-block-c ui-bar-a"><div align="right" style="padding-top:3px;height:33px;height:40px;"><a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext" style="margin-top:5px;"></a></div></div></div></div>');    
            $('[data-role=page]#' + seq + ' [data-role=content]').load(file);
        }

var images = $('.items');
    var CELL_WIDTH = 5;
    var ASPECT = 1.5;

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        step: 5,
        min: 70,
        max: 200,
        value: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var size = (CELL_WIDTH * ui.value / 100) + "em";
            images.stop(true).animate({width: size * ASPECT, height: size}, 250);
        }
    });
```

Dialog.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>XML File</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <!-- <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-dialog-contain
        {
            opacity: 1 !important;
            background: #FFFFFF !important;
        }
        .ui-dialog .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext
        {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .ui-dialog-background
        {
            opacity: 0.5;
            display: block !important;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        }

        .ui-dialog-background.pop.in
        {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        }

        .ui-dialog
        {
            min-height: 100% !important;
            background: transparent !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, ui) {
                // make parent page transparent
                ui.prevPage.addClass("ui-dialog-background");
            });

            $('div[data-role="dialog"]').live('pagehide', function (e, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-background").removeClass("ui-dialog-background");
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Dialog</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="slider">
           <label for="slider-mini">Text Size:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle please.

Comment: ok but the content is present in a file i'm dynamically loading the files to display on the page.

Comment: So use a demo instead, Some lorem-ipsum text or something.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G546T/ this is somewhat related to my way. When you click on the listitems it will turn to another page. In that page we have a button(data-icon= bars) in footer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G546T/1/ updated one

Comment: Your code is way too complicated to begin and understand where's the problem. I looked into it, and don't know what's happening there. You should look at the problem with less variables in it, and apart from the fact that we will be able to better help you, you will likely find your problem.

Comment: bcz i'm loading xml file that's why it looks like that..you see the resizing the text

Comment: I was not able to see any text that should be resized. My suggestion - make a demo of what you want to accomplish. When you get that to work, then expand your code to it's final form that you want.

Comment: are you see my code correctly..i'm getting the data from the xml file. In the home page i'm displaying all the <section> and <content> tags of text. when we click on the <content> tags means (content1,content2...) that particular file should open. The file path is present in the xml file <content> tag of "file" attribute

Comment: That file data i'm displaying in the dynamic page...